# Ruby on rails many-to many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I'm fairly new to Rails so this might seem like a basic question.

I am creating a cinema application and require the tables Bookings and Ticket_Type.

Bookings has the attributes: user_id, showing_id, adult_seats, child_seats, concession_seats.

Ticket_Type will have the attributes: type, price.

This relationship would be many to many, as one booking could have many ticket types, such as by having 2 adults and 2 children, and one ticket type, such as "Child", could have many bookings.

But how do I map this in Ruby on Rails? Or would it be through having a table inbetween called something like Booking_Ticket that would store the booking_id and ticket_type_id?

What I will need my application to calculate, for instance, is the total price of a booking - so if a booking has 2 adults, 1 concession, and 2 children, and in ticket_type an adult costs 7.50, a concession 6, and a child 5, then the total would be 31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think that there is a relationship between `Bookings` and `TicketType`.  `TicketType` is merely a settings table in your application where you are storing pricing data.  Since `adult_seats`, `child_seats`, `concession_seats` are integer values, there is no direct association between the 2 tables.

All you really need the `TicketType` for is reference on cost.  I seems that this table will not hold much data; I would just load that data prior to determining cost of the the booking.

Comment: Load that data from where? So you're saying not to have the table `TicketType`, but where would the prices be stored?

Comment: No, I am not saying that.  I am saying that your `TicketType` table is holding "static, referential" data.  You do not need to associate it to `Bookings`.  In the method where you calculated cost, load the pricing data via AR call:  `pricing = TicketType.all`.  Then reference the ticket when calculating the cost:  `adult_cost = pricing.find{|p| p.type.eql?('adult')}.price * adult_seats`

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I'm on the same wavelength. Have Bookings as a table and TicketType as a table but there's no association between them. Store the pricings in the TicketType, e.g. Adult: £10, and then in the Bookings.rb model have a method that gets all the prices through `pricing = TicketType.all` and then work out the cost of each individual ticket through `pricing.find{|p| p.type.eql?('adult')}.price * adult_seats`?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you!